# Bash script find all images and mogrify images

Tags: bash, find, mogrify

We have images imported into our system at night, and I need to make sure all the images are at least 1000px wide or tall and I need to exclude images that are in the cache folder.

I'm no bash expert. I've pieced this together from several sources.
I've used find to find all the product images and exclude the cache folder here.

```
find /overnight/media/catalog/product/ \( -name cache -prune \) -o -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image'
```

I need to run mogrify on each image file that is found.

```
mogrify -resize "1000x1000>"
```

How do I do this?  If my approach is not the best please let me know what would be a better approach.

Comment: You might run `identify` to see if image even needs to be resized

Comment: @Sierra good idea, can you give me a suggestion on how to implement that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took what Benjamin AND Sierra suggested and came up with this. 
It looks to see if the image is of the proper size before it runs mogrify on the file.  I'm sure there is a "better" way, but this seems to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
set -e
minimumWidth=1000
minimumHeight=1000

FILES=$(find /overnight/media/catalog/product/  \( -name cache -prune \) -o -name '*' -type f -exec file {} \; | awk -F: '{ if ($2 ~/[Ii]mage|EPS/) print $1}')

AMOUNT=`echo $FILES | wc -w`

COUNTER=0

if [ ! -z "$FILES" ];
then
    for F in $FILES
    do 
        imageWidth="$(identify -format "%w" "$F")"
        imageHeight="$(identify -format "%h" "$F")"
        if [ "$imageWidth" -ge "$minimumWidth" ] || [ "$imageHeight" -ge "$minimumHeight" ]; then
            echo "Not Changed. " ''"$imageWidth"x"$imageHeight"'' "$F"
        else
            echo "Initial Size"
            ls -lah "$F" | awk -F " " {'print $5'}
            mogrify -resize ''"$minimumWidth"x"$minimumHeight<"'' "$F"
            echo "Resized Size"
            ls -lah "$F" | awk -F " " {'print $5'}
           let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
           NewimageWidth="$(identify -format "%w" "$F")"
           NewimageHeight="$(identify -format "%h" "$F")"
           echo "Mogrifyed. $NewimageWidth"x"$NewimageHeight"
        fi

    done

fi
echo "Done! $COUNTER of $AMOUNT files found and changed!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your find command works as you intend, something like this should suffice

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

FILES=`find /overnight/media/catalog/product/ \( -name cache -prune \) -o -name '*' -exec file {} \; | grep -o -P '^.+: \w+ image'`
AMOUNT=`echo $FILES | wc -w`

if [ ! -z "$FILES" ];
then
    mogrify -resize "1000x1000>" $FILES
fi

echo "Done! $AMOUNT files found and changed!"
```

......